# sed to replace spaces in quotation marks

Tags: command-line, sed

I have a file containing a long passage of text as follows

an excerpt from the file is

> Mother cooked eggs for them, and they ate their breakfast hungrily. " It's lovely to be in the country! " said Jo,

whil i would like it to read

> Mother cooked eggs for them, and they ate their breakfast hungrily. "It's lovely to be in the country!" said Jo,

is theres any way to achieve this using sed or any other cli tool

Answer (score 1):

If it's only to replace once in each line, you can use `sed 's/" \(.*\) "/"\1"/'`. Otherwise, try `sed 's/" \([^"]*\) "/"\1"/g'`.

Example:

```
$ sed 's/" \(.*\) "/"\1"/' input_file_name
Mother cooked eggs for them, and they ate their breakfast hungrily. "It's lovely to be in the country!" said Jo,
```

Comment: the second example worked great for me thanks i appreciate it

Comment: But that won't work if the quotation spans several lines.

Comment: @MichaelVehrs Yes, `sed` is usually simply used for processing line by line.